# How to concatenate 2 or 3 physical disks to create one larger usable volume in Centos7

Tags: linux, storage, ssd-hdd-hybrid

I will like to apply the concept of concatenation of multiple physical disks and create one larger disk for my my storage, and I am using Centos7 as the my server. I have 2 types of disks: one is an SSD and the other one is an normal Seagate storage hard drive. I will like to know if this is possible.

Comment: While technically you can concatenate dissimilar types of drive I really wouldn't recommend it. Also bear in mind _statistically_ that concatenating two disk drives will almost halve the lifetime of the resultant filesystem. Given modern spinning disk warranties that could be as little as six months.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible using LVM (Logical Volume Manager).  You can create a single logical volume, then add both disks as physical volumes.  This can be done during the install process by choosing manual partitioning.

If you're working with an existing system, the process may be more difficult.  If I remember right, CentOS 7 creates LVMs for storage by default.  You can check by looking at /etc/fstab.  If the mount devices start with /dev/mapper, you're in luck.  Your system already has LVM set up.

If you're adding a new disk to the system, you can follow this guide to add it to your existing volume group:

https://www.tecmint.com/add-new-disks-using-lvm-to-linux/